# Update rally's task revision

Tags: rally

could someone give me an example on how to update a task's revision using javascript?

I just created a task with

```
rallyDataSource.create("task", {"Name": "DEV: Do Work", "WorkProduct": thisDefect}, onCreateComplete,onCreateError);
```

Now I want to update description of the first revision of the task from "Original revision" to "Auto-created task". I tried to get _ref of that first revision, but don't know how. Using

```
function onCreateComplete(object, warnings) {
    var createdObject = object;
    rallyDataSource.update({"_ref": createdObject.RevisionHistory.Revisions[0]._ref, "Description": "Auto-created task"}, onComplete,onError);
}
```

does not work

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisions are a read-only collection - and are meant to provide a reliable record of changes to an Artifact, so you won't be able to update a Revision using AppSDK or Webservices API.

I would recommend that you accomplish your end goal (i.e. providing a descriptor indicating that the Task was auto-created) via a naming convention in either the Task's Name, or its Description text.

Comment: btw Mark, what if I want to update the discussion instead, it should be doable right?

Comment: I tried rallyDataSource.create("discussion" ...), but it said unknown type "discussion"

Comment: I've figured it out, it should be "ConversationPost" instead of "discussion"